# nodejs socket.io closes connection before upgrading to websocket

Tags: c++, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to write a C++ client to talk to a WebSocket server written using NodeJS and socket.io. I can't get the C++ client to establish the WebSocket connection; the server drops the connection right after the client requests that the HTTP connection be upgraded to WebSocket.

I used tcpdump to watch the packets going back and forth. When I use the WebSocket server from a browser, it works great and the tcpdump output shows packets going back and forth. But when I try to connect to the server using the C++ client, the WebSocket connection never gets established. The output from tcpdump shows the upgrade request being sent to the server followed immediately by the server dropping the connection.

I then tried replicating the sequence of events using `nc`. I connected to the server (running on port 8080) and copy-pasted the exact set of headers that were sent by the browser, as captured by tcpdump. Even with this duplicate of the working headers, the connection was dropped.

There is no output on the server end indicating why the connection gets dropped.

Here are the headers I sent:

```
GET /socket.io/?type=player&EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=7MdCLhT_8cTsd6F4AAAC HTTP/1.1
host: localhost:8080
connection: Upgrade
pragma: no-cache
cache-control: no-cache
upgrade: websocket
origin: http://localhost:8080
sec-websocket-version: 13
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8
cookie: io=7MdCLhT_8cTsd6F4AAAC
sec-websocket-key: nm7f0TlagGC2S6sAUPHwaQ==
sec-websocket-extensions: permessage-deflate;client_max_window_bits
x-forwarded-proto: http
x-forwarded-port: 80
x-forwarded-for: 127.0.0.1
```

I'm completely stumped why socket.io isn't upgrading the connection. According to the documentation I've seen for the WebSocket protocol this ought to work. The only think I can think of is Socket.IO is expecting a cookie or some other magic incantation to get the client talking to the server.

Comment: I read somewhere that `socket.io` uses custom `websocket` protocol. That's why probably, `c++` client is not able to `socket.io` server.

Comment: I think you're right. I finally ended up using the C++ library from socket.io and it works well.